# Query the JSON objects in the Hazelcast

Tags: json, hazelcast

I'm trying to Query in the Hazelcast instance

Below is my code:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        HazelcastInstance hazelCast = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
        IMap<String, HazelcastJsonValue> map = hazelCast.getMap("map1");

        map.put("0001",
                new HazelcastJsonValue("{\r\n" + "  \"id\": \"0001\",\r\n" + "  \"name\": \"willaims\"\r\n" + "}"));

        map.put("0002",
                new HazelcastJsonValue("{\r\n" + "  \"id\": \"0002\",\r\n" + "  \"name\": \"peter\"\r\n" + "}"));

        try (SqlResult result = hazelCast.getSql().execute("SELECT name FROM map1")) {
            for (SqlRow row : result) {
                String name = row.getObject(0);
                System.err.println(name);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to extract the name field from json but I'm getting the below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JSON objects are not supported.
    at com.hazelcast.sql.impl.schema.map.sample.MapSampleMetadataResolver.resolve(MapSampleMetadataResolver.java:73)
    ... 11 more
```

I directly wants to query the json objects and filter particular fields without convert them into model class.

Any suggestions on this would be really helpful...

Comment: I see no `WHERE` clause in your code. Do you want to query or to get all items?

Comment: Hi Nicolas I have edited my question please check.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.1.2/sql/querying-imap#key-and-value-fields)

`HazelcastJsonValue` is not yet supported (in 4.1) for the new SQL style.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @oliv for a better answer. You can actually do this with Jet 4.4:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Config config = new Config();
         config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getAutoDetectionConfig().setEnabled(false);
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
        
        JetConfig jetConfig = new JetConfig();
        jetConfig.setHazelcastConfig(config);

        JetInstance jetInstance = Jet.newJetInstance(jetConfig);
        
        String definition = "CREATE MAPPING IF NOT EXISTS map1("
                + "    __key VARCHAR,"
                + "    id VARCHAR,"
                + "    name VARCHAR"
                + ") TYPE IMap"
                + " OPTIONS ( "
                + " 'keyFormat' = 'java',"
                + " 'keyJavaClass' = '" + String.class.getCanonicalName() + "',"
                + " 'valueFormat' = 'java',"
                + " 'valueJavaClass' = '" + HazelcastJsonValue.class.getCanonicalName() + "'"
                + " )";
        
        jetInstance.getSql().execute(definition);
        
        IMap<String, HazelcastJsonValue> map = jetInstance.getMap("map1");

        map.put("0001",
                new HazelcastJsonValue("{ \"id\": \"0001\", \"name\": \"willaims\" }"));

        map.put("0002",
                new HazelcastJsonValue("{ \"id\": \"0002\", \"name\": \"peter\" }"));

        try (SqlResult result = jetInstance.getSql().execute("SELECT * FROM map1 AS m")) {
            for (SqlRow row : result) {
                System.err.println(row);
            }
        }
        
        jetInstance.shutdown();
    }
```

You need `com.hazelcast.jet.hazelcast-jet-sql:4.4`

Comment: Hi Neil Stevension I appreciate  your efforts. but I have a question like what if I have a nested json objects. example:- json objects inside an array